# c++ avoid code duplication operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, code-duplication

My Question is the following, let's say I have this classes:

```
class ID3OBJ
{
public:
    const double X;
    const double Y;
    const double Z;
    ID3OBJ(double x, double y, double z);
    ID3OBJ();
    const ID3OBJ operator+ (const ID3OBJ param) const;
}
class Vector : public ID3OBJ
    {
    public:
        Vector(double x, double y, double z);
        Vector();
        /*const Vector const operator+ (const Vector param); */
}
class Point : public ID3OBJ
    {
    public:
        Point(double x, double y, double z);
        Point();
}
class Plane : public ID3OBJ
    {
    public:
        Point Origin;
        Vector Direction1;
        Vector Direction2;
        Vector NormalVector;
        Plane(Point Origin, Vector Normalvector);
        Plane(Point Origin, Vector Direction1, Vector Direction2);
        Plane();
}
class D3GON : public ID3OBJ, public Plane
    {
    public:
        std::vector<Point> EdgePoints;
        D3GON(Point P1, Point P2, Point P3);
    };
```

In my current code I have to redefine the operator overload for each class, how can I avoid this code-duplication?

Do I have to add convert-functions?

I use const member-values, to deny objects changes after creation. Meaning if any low-level object has to be changed it has to be replaced by a new one. See my operator overload below:

```
// operator overwrites:
    const ID3OBJ ID3OBJ::operator+ (const ID3OBJ param) const { double newX, newY, newZ; newX = X + param.X; newY = Y + param.Y; newZ = Z + param.Z; return ID3OBJ(newX, newY, newZ); }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: If all `countableObjectsInterface` add the same way then just provide that and no `Animals operator+(Animals obj)`. If `Animals` and `Sloths` add differently you will have to provide different implementations, no way around it. And maybe adding 2 `Sloths` that create more `Sloths` is not really the right thing to do at all.

Comment: @n.m.: Well they've got to eat _something_, though I hear they prefer lettuce.

Comment: This is an example, I am working with 3D objects. If I don't provide any overloads for my subclasses, the operator gives back the base class. I ll add the operator definition.

Comment: Please post a real life example. The answer very much depends on the exact details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @n.m.
See above

Comment: In your new question, I cannot guess what will be the addition of two Point or of two Plane...

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's rather easy, the X Y and Z coordinates of a Plane describe its origin, a Point is just a subtype of Vector, the only difference is it can be plottet while vectors cant.

Comment: With this design you know you can add a point and a plane, and the result will be ID3OBJ (what's that?) With the CRTP design you can't do that, but it looks like you will be able to add two planes (meaningless) and the result will be an under-constructed plane (dangerous). All in all, placing `operator+` in the common base of all geometry objects doesn't make too much sense either mathematically or from the software engineering standpoint. You can add two vectors, but vectors don't even live in the same space as 3d shapes like points and planes.

Comment: @n.m. Well honestly I used to have a plus and minus function in vector, in the original c# project, which i now replaced with the operator. But I do plan to move the operator to the vector class, which is the superclass of point (since both are 3d-objects ;) ), which should fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is the way to go here. It is slightly more complex because you want multiple derivation levels. But here is a code example:

```
template <class T>
class ID3OBJ
{
public:
   double X,Y,Z;
   T operator+(const T& obj) const {
       T t;
       t.X = X + obj.X;
       t.Y=Y+obj.Y;
       t.Z=z+obj.Z;
       return t;
   }
};

class Vector : public ID3OBJ<Vector>
{
public:
    // some stuff
};

class Point : public Vector, public ID3OBJ<Point>
{
public:
    // X, Y and Z exist twice, once in Vector, once in ID3OBJ<Point>, so we must disambiguate
    using ID3OBJ<Point>::X;
    using ID3OBJ<Point>::Y;
    using ID3OBJ<Point>::Z;
};
```

You can add `Vector` (and you'll get `Vector`) or just `Point` and you'll get `Point`. More interestingly, if you add `Point` and `Vector`, you get an `Vector` result because the overloaded operator + resolution will select `Vector::operator +`

Comment: Thank you, thats what I've been looking for :)